# Transfer Success, but no data in the database (Data Migration tool)

Tags: data-migration, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to transfer JSON file to mongodb in microsoft azure using Microsoft's Data Migration tool. There are no errors generated and its says transferred. But there is no data in the database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynxwe.png)
I looked everywhere but doesn't find any solution. If you could help, that would great.